# NHibernate: trying to save collection of children of the same object type fails

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class that has a one-to-many relationship within itself, when trying to save a collection of children, only the first child is being saved, here is my mapping:

```
 <class name="AMU" table="AMU">
        <id name="ID" column="ID">
          <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="_Manager" class="AMU" column="ParentID" access="field"/>
        <many-to-one name="User" column="UserID"/>
        <many-to-one name="MCT" column="MctID"/>
        <set name="ManagedAMUs" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false">
          <key column="ParentID"/>
          <one-to-many class="AMU"/>
        </set>
      </class>
```

here is the class definition:

```
public class AMU : TABS.Components.BaseEntity
    {
        public AMU()
        {
            this.User = null;
            this.Manager = null;
            this.ManagedAMUs = new List<AMU>();
        }

        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        private AMU _Manager;
        public virtual AMU Manager
        {
            get { return _Manager; }
            set { _Manager = value; }
        }
        public virtual ICollection<AMU> ManagedAMUs { get; set; }
public virtual MCT MCT { get; set; }
}
```

when I use a for loop to add several AMUs to a parent AMU

> ```
> foreach(var amu in AMUList)
> {
>     myAMU.ManagedAMUs.Add(amu);
> }
> ```

and then saving the parent AMU, it only saves one child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the fact, that NHiberante `<set>` (in comparison with `<bag>`) is representing a collection of unique records. How to fix it? There are two, very different ways:

1. change the mapping from `<set>` to `<bag>`
2. implement the `bool Equals(object obj)` and `int GetHashCode()` in the *`AMU`* class

The first solution, is in fact saying: collection could contain one ***same*** item many times.

The second solution is about handling the word ***same***. How to check if the objects are the same? well from perspective of the `<set>` the methods `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` are called.

In this case we need to distinguish child objects *(becuase of hierarchical nature, the parent as well)*. It should

- not be based on the surrogated key (ID) but
- e.g. on properties like *Code* or *Name*... or combination. Or in the example above on the User.ID

NOTE: By the way, even if we change `<set>` to be a `<bag>`, our mapped entities should override these methods. It is simply a good practice.